# Outlook Online: I can’t seem to filter according to sender

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sorting

***Outlook Online: I can’t seem to filter according to sender!***

I am working with Outlook online, chrome browser, from a desktop—not a phone app / Mac OS.) I did check some community answers, But I didn’t see anything that answers this (Sorry if I missed it!)

I do have screenshots that show my options when I try to filter, showing that it does *not seem to be an option anywhere*. Answers I have read online point to solutions I don’t see (Go to view tab, arrange by etc.)

I have tried thru three different browsers, including  browsers that had never accessed that Outlook / Microsoft Office 365 site before, so I don’t think it’s a cache issue. It’s a rather basic function don’t you think? I used to be able to do this when I had Outlook in my computer but online—no.

Writing a “rule” for ANY emails I get to be somehow filterable by alphabetizing seems unwieldy. I suspect that the online version simply—for whatever ridiculous reason—does not offer this common-sense sorting option. I can’t use the desktop version of Outlook for various reasons. All I want to know at this point is if Outlook online, reached thru a desktop, not a phone, doesn’t offer this option. If so I can stop wasting my time trying to go thru filters, FAQs, rules, etc etc.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You might post your screenshots.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I did that. Apparently not. (I am new here) How would I do that now?

Comment: Press the Edit button to add the links to your images.

Answer (score 0):

Select Filter at the top of your inbox.

Under Sort by, choose from to sort your email.

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer. That is EXACTLY my problem. It does NOT offer me that option. I know from the past how to filter and was able to do this in Outlook on my desktop system. It does not seem to be available for outlook online (accessed thru a desktop, not a phone. I thought I uploaded screenshots (I’m new.) Not sure how to do that apparently.